# Efficiently repeating pandas dataframe rows based on log data column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

I'm working with log data for a classification problem. Each row consists of a given session's action and each session is divided into subsessions. My objective is to repeat previous subsession's actions in given subsessions (retrieving the last N) in a given session. I'm having trouble coming up with time efficient solutions for my 4M+ row dataset.

**Simplified example**

Note - Other features are omitted, `action` corresponds to the subsession action index and `orig_action` is just a helper for the example, where `A2.1` corresponds to action 1 from the original subsession A2, `A3.1` corresponds to action 1 from the original subsession A3, and so on.

```
# - Original dataframe

  session  subsession  action
0       A           1       1
1       A           2       1
2       A           2       2
3       A           3       1
4       B           1       1

# - Expanded dataframe
# Session A:
# Subsession 2 now encompasses last N actions from subsessions 1 and 2
# Subsession 3 now encompasses last N actions from subsessions 1, 2 and 3
# Check above note for orig_action explanation.

  session  subsession  action  orig_action
0       A           1       1         A1.1
1       A           2       1         A1.1
2       A           2       2         A2.1
3       A           2       3         A2.2
4       A           3       1         A1.1
5       A           3       2         A2.1
6       A           3       3         A2.2
7       A           3       4         A3.1
8       B           1       1         B1.1
```

The number of subsessions can reach up to 500.

Does anyone have any idea of how I might be able to do this without it taking days with an iterative loop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the output DF given your data. Can you explain it more ?

Comment: @pyOliv sure! In the original dataframe we have 2 different sessions (A and B). Session A has 3 subsessions and each of these has 1, 2 and 1 actions respectively - row 0 corresponds to action 1 of subsession 1 in A, row 1 corresponds to action 1 of subsession 2 in A. 
The output (expanded) dataframe, should repeat previous subsession's actions. i.e. subsession 1 is unchanged but subsession 2 should have the original subsession 1's repeated rows + the original sub 2's rows; sub 3 = sub 1+2+3. The orig_action column is a pointer for how the expanded dataframe's rows relate to the original's.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If I take the subsession A2 as example, I don't understand how it is possible to output an action 3, while we only have actions 1 and 2 as inputs.

Comment: In the output for A2 I want to have both the actions from the original A2 plus the actions from the previous A# sessions, in this case A1. So, the first action in the output's A2 is actually A1's single action repeated and the following two actions are the two old A2 actions, hence why there are 3! A3's output will be A1+A2+A3 = 1+2+1 = 4 actions. 
I hope that helps clear it out! Sorry if it seems a bit confusing.

Comment: OK, I got it. we have `subaction` in the original DF, and you want to parse them as `session action`. I think you can  speed up a little the code using `pandas` but I don't see how to build a pythonic version without a loop.